# while dentro de un forEach

Tags: nodejs, while

buenas tardes una solo para hacer una consulta puedo meter un un while dentro de un forEach es que tengo este código

```
 feed.items.forEach(function(post) {
                            var post = {
                                _id: {
                                    post_url: post.link,
                                    title: {
                                        main: post.title
                                    },
                                    media_cover: post.enclosure.url,
                                    iconSite: '',
                                    date_publish: Moment.tz(post.pubDate).format('ddd, DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ', 'ddd, DD MMMM YY HH:mm:ss ZZ'),
                                }
                            };
                            data_block.posts.push(post);
                        });
```

funciona todo bien pero quiero limitarlo a que me a que me muestre solo 6 post en ves de todo alguien me dar una idea como realizar eso, los datos los traigo en rssfeed.

intente hacer de esta forma pero no funciona

```
feed.items.forEach(function(post) {
                            var c = 0
                            while (c < 6) {
                                var post = {
                                    _id: {
                                        post_url: post.link,
                                        title: {
                                            main: post.title
                                        },
                                        media_cover: post.enclosure.url,
                                        iconSite: '',
                                        date_publish: Moment.tz(post.pubDate).format('ddd, DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ', 'ddd, DD MMMM YY HH:mm:ss ZZ'),
                                    }
                                };
                                c++
                            }
                            data_block.posts.push(post);
                        });
```

le agradecería mucho su orientación..

Comment: Eso no lo limitaría, al contrario te mostraría más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se `nodejs` pero me imagino que sera lo mismo que javascript.

Al método `forEach` le puedes pasar el indice también, así que puedes poner una condición para que haga el `push` solo 6 veces.

```
feed.items.forEach(function(post,index)  {
   if(index<6){
    ...
    data_block.posts.push(post);
   }
});
```

Comment: O puedes hacer: `feed.items.filter((_, index) => index <= 6)`.

Comment: gracias me sirvió

Answer (score 1):

Si `feed.items` es muy largo, supongamos un largo de `1.000`, el contra de usar [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) es que una vez cumplida la condición (`index < 6`) no se puede detener la iteración, es decir, el proceso continuara hasta recorer/evaluar los `1.000`.

Si te interesa hacerlo mas eficiente (*iterar lo justo y necesario*), lo que deberías usar es un [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for), el cual se puede interrumpir con un `break`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let feed = {
  // Creamos un arreglo de 1000 indices numerado
  items: Array.from({length: 1000}, (v, i) => i + 5)
}

for(const [index, post] of feed.items.entries()) {
  console.log(index);
  
  // ... Aquí tu código
  
  if (index === 5) {
    // Detenemos la iteración
    break;
  }
};
```